# Create JSON format of PHP dynamic multiple fields

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, json

I need to create a specific JSON format of the data which I received from the PHP form. If I can make the right array then I could convert it into JSON but could not find how... My form has multiple fields which takes the data and convert into an array like this

```
    Array
    (
        [user_id] => 
        [title2] => Billing
        [sub_title2] => to
        [emails2] => abc@gmail.com
        [sub_title3] => cc
        [emails3] => xyz@gmail.com
        [sub_title4] => for
        [emails4] => john@gmail.com
        [title5] => Free
        [sub_title5] => cc
        [emails5] => abc@gmail.com
        [sub_title6] => adf
        [emails6] => ben@gmail.com,ten@gmail.com
    )
```

This is the code which takes the data

```
    $(document).on("click", "#add_section", function (e) {
      i++; 
      k++;
    
     var Html1 ='<div id="email_section'+k+'" style="margin-top: 20px" class="form-group row">';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-9">';
                Html1 += '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Add Section'+i+'<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-9">';
                Html1 += '<input class=" form-control" id="title'+i+'[]" name="title'+i+'" type="text" placeholder="Sales" />';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-12">';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-9">';
                Html1 += '<label class="control-label col-lg-3"></label>';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-2">';
                Html1 += '<input class=" form-control" id="sub_title'+i+'[]" name="sub_title'+i+'" type="text" placeholder="to" />';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-7">';
                Html1 += '<input class=" form-control" id="emails'+i+'[]" name="emails'+i+'" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" />';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '<div class="col-lg-2">';
                Html1 += '<span class="btn btn-primary add_email_row" id="'+k+'">Add</span>';
                Html1 += '</div>';
                Html1 += '</div>';
    
      $('.modal-body').append(Html1); 
    
    
    });
    
    
    
    $(document).on("click", ".add_email_row", function (e) {
      i++; 
      k++;
    
      var section = $(this).attr("id");
    
      var Html = '<div id="row'+i+'" class="row">'; 
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-12">';
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 20px;"></div>';
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-9">';
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-2"><input class=" form-control" id="sub_title'+i+'[]" name="sub_title'+i+'" type="text" placeholder="to" /></div>';
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-7"><input class=" form-control" id="emails'+i+'[]" name="emails'+i+'" type="text" placeholder="emails" /></div>';
      Html += '<div class="col-sm-3"><a type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</a></div>';
      Html += '</div></div></div>';
    
    $('#email_section'+section+'').append(Html); 
    
    });
```

The JSON format i want is

```
    {
       "billing":{
          "to":"abc@email.com",
          "cc":"xyz@email.com",
          "adf":"mail@email.com",
          "from":""
       },
       "free":{
          "to":"abc@gmail.com,",
          "cc":"xyz@email.com",
          "adf":""
       }
    }
```

[The UI of the PHP form for the understanding of the multiple dynamic fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWEOF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form can be changed, then change the inputs to arrays. Also encapsulate your two blocks and keep them in the same increment logic:

```
<script>

function addSection(i, k)
{
    var Html1 =
    '<div id="email_section'+k+'" style="margin-top: 20px" class="form-group row">' +
        '<div class="col-lg-12">' +
            '<div class="col-lg-9">' +
                '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Add Section'+i+'<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-9">' +
                    '<input class=" form-control" id="title'+i+'" name="title['+i+']" type="text" placeholder="Sales" />' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-12">' +
            '<div class="col-lg-9">' +
                '<label class="control-label col-lg-3"></label>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-2">' +
                    '<input class=" form-control" id="sub_title'+i+'" name="sub_title['+i+'][]" type="text" placeholder="to" />' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-7">' +
                    '<input class=" form-control" id="emails'+i+'" name="emails['+i+'][]" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" />' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-2">' +
                '<span class="btn btn-primary add_email_row" id="'+k+'">Add</span>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    $('.modal-body').append(Html1); 
}

function addEmail(obj, i, k)
{
    var section = obj.attr("id");
    var Html =
    '<div id="row'+i+'" class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-sm-12">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-left: 20px;"></div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-9">' +
                '<div class="col-sm-2"><input class=" form-control" id="sub_title'+i+'" name="sub_title['+i+'][]" type="text" placeholder="to" /></div>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-7"><input class=" form-control" id="emails'+i+'" name="emails['+i+'][]" type="text" placeholder="emails" /></div>' +
                '<div class="col-sm-3"><a type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</a></div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
    
    $('#email_section'+section).append(Html); 
}
    
var i   =   0;
var k   =   0;
$(document).on("click", "#add_section,.add_email_row", function (e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('add_email_row')) {
        addEmail($(this), i, k);
    }
    else {
        i++; 
        k++;
        addSection(i, k);
    }
});

</script>
```

You should be left with:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [1] => Section 1
            [2] => Section 2
        )

    [sub_title] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => subtitle1
                    [1] => subtitle2
                    [2] => subtitle3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => subtitle1
                )

        )

    [emails] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email1@example.com
                    [1] => email2@example.com
                    [2] => email3@example.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => email1@example.com
                )

        )

)
```

From here it's much easier to get your array in php:

```
$array    =   $_POST;
$new    =   [];
foreach($array['title'] as $k => $title) {
    $new[$title]    =   array_combine($array['sub_title'][$k], $array['emails'][$k]);
}

echo json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Which would give you:

```
 {
    "Section 1": {
        "subtitle1": "email1@example.com",
        "subtitle2": "email2@example.com",
        "subtitle3": "email3@example.com"
    },
    "Section 2": {
        "subtitle1": "email1@example.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u soo much Rasclatt...amazing this is exactly what I need